# TypeError: jQuery(...).find(...).carousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

For some reason I'm getting js error that the carousel is not a function although I have all the scripts connected, e.g. jquery.js and bootstrap.js before calling the script.js where I have the carousel function.

I have the code working just fine in the website but when I moved to web app I'm getting that error, although the elements are same.

So in the master page I have this in the header part:

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All scripts are loaded fine, and once I have the page open I have this exception:

[image]

In script.js I have this:

```
jQuery('myCarousel').find('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 8000
});
```

I'll say again, the same structure is working fine in the older website, not sure why its different here.

### Update

Html markup generated:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item">
                        <div class="title"><h2>header</h2></div>
                        <figure><img src="/assets/images/gallery/YCQE183J8RHACYCHLISF.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        <div class="carousel-caption"><a href="#">Learn more about our programs. </a><div class="arrow-right"></div></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                        <div class="title"><h2>text1</h2></div>
                        <figure><img src="/assets/images/gallery/IB819WTCBL3HRM7NZ2CA.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        <div class="carousel-caption"><a href="">text3</a><div class="arrow-right"></div></div></div>
                        <div class="item"><div class="title"><h2>text2</h2></div><figure><img src="/assets/images/gallery/6KCDVUKYCAXH91M6MWAU.jpg" alt=""></figure><div class="carousel-caption"><a href="#">text4</a><div class="arrow-right"></div></div></div>

                    </div>
                    <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left"></a>
                    <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right"></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where is the carousel script?

Comment: @debin: That will make no difference and the selector is wrong unless there is a `<myCarousel>` tag in the page :)

Comment: that's correct (y) @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: Q: Which specific carousel are you using? According the script shown you are not using any :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing any carousel script. That will cause the `carousel is not a function` message. It is not part of jQuery and is only part of boostrap if you have the full version. Otherwise you need to include the bootstrap `carousel.js` plugin file too. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Also your selector will not work as `myCarousel` is an id, so should have been `#myCarousel` but `.carousel` is on the same element so `find` will not match anything under it:

try:

```
jQuery('#myCarousel.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 8000
});
```

or better yet (as id selectors are the most efficient) just:

```
jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 8000
});
```

Comment: thanks but both solutions are giving me the same error

Comment: @Laziale: Again - What carousel are you using? Boostrap's?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/d50cbfd24862378bc039327626ec0424.png I'm able to  get the control as you can see, but can't apply the carousel. Not sure about the 2nd question, since this code was already working in older solution, we just moved to web app instead of website (.net wise)

Comment: @Laziale: Okay, so your selector is now fixed with above, but your carousel code is not firing. Is your bootstrap version a full version (with carousel)? I would guess not. You can just add the `carousel.js` bootstrap plugin afterwards to test. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have to add the code inside the document ready function `$( document ).ready(function() { });` and the error went away. Hope it'll help someone.